# FragmentStatePagerAdapter not calling getItem

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

The problem: I have a ViewPager setup with a FragmentStatePagerAdapter that uses a global arraylist for the contents of its fragments. When I want to update this global array, I simply call the `arraylist.add()` method, instantiate a new FragmentStatePagerAdapter and a new ViewPager. However, for some reason, the Adapter isn't calling getItem at all. Not that it's data set is empty (it isn't) or anything... it simply isn't being called. I even set a log to test it. Here's my code:

```
// Create the adapter that will return a fragment for event
SectionsPagerAdapter adapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

// Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
pager.setAdapter(adapter);

/**
 * A FragmentStatePagerAdapter that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * an index of the global events array
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    /**
     * Called to instantiate the fragment for the given page
     */
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Log.v("Miles", "getItem called");
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        return EventFragment.newInstance(events.get(position));
    }

    /**
     * Total number of pages (fragments) there are
     * Given by size of the global events array minus 1
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return events.size() - 1;
    }
}
```

Are there any problems I could have with this setup? I can verify that the global arraylist has data inside of it, but no fragment is being instantiated to reflect that.

Comment: You don't need to create a new adapter. Add the item to your list and call `notifyDataSetChanged` on the existing adapter. `getItem` is only called when the ViewPager needs the next page. It will not be called right away when you change the adapter data.

Comment: Right, so when I add the item to the arraylist, then go back to the activity holding the viewpager, nothing is displayed. As in, the item I just added to the arraylist is not there. I confirmed that there are no new fragments being added to the adapter by calling 'getCount()'.

Comment: And you are calling `notifyDataSetChanged`?

Comment: I am, yeah. Sorry for the late response, was in a meeting.

Comment: So I fixed the problem by making my adapter a global variable. I was hesitant to do this because I think it looks ugly, but it works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to override getItemPosition

override fun getItemPosition(`object`: Any): Int {
return POSITION_NONE
}

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33032720)